# Why is connectedness in the majority of graph theoretical results?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Is there any reason why, for example, in the
theorems about embeddings of graphs, at some point
the authors states that all graphs are connected.

To be more concrete, after prop 3.1, and 3.2 [in this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82194138.pdf),
the author says "we shall always assume that graphs are connected."

Why? is this just for simplicity? Or what if we consider
disconnected graphs? Can these graphs also be embedded in surfaces?

Answer (score 4):

It is probably just for simplicity.  Many results in graph theory apply to each connected component individually, so connectivity is a common simplifying assumption (without loss of generality).  For example, a graph is $k$-colorable if and only if each component is $k$-colorable.