# Every Planar Graph is 6-colorable

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

Some proofs for the theorem that states that every planar graph is 6-colorable usually assume both the $G$ is simple and connected. The simple assumption is because coloring is not affected by loops or parallel edges, but what about connectivity?

I guess the reason behind connectivity is to connect each component separately because different components don't interact with each other with respect to coloring, but this justification for connectivity assumption is not clear for me, could you please rephrase or explain what does that mean?

Comment: See also: [Why is connectedness in the majority of graph theoretical results?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3921457/400626)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can 6-color each connected component, then you can 6-color the whole graph, by taking the union of the 6-colorings. So you only need to prove the theorem for a connected graph, and then it extends to unconnected graphs as a trivial corollary.

Comment: I don't get how the graph has components if we begin with $G$ that is connected originally and 6-colorable. Or it means connected components such that there is k components that are connected with each other?

Comment: @Avra: There are two cases: The graph is connected or the graph is disconnected. If the graph is connected, it is composed of a single connected component, and you run the proof once. If the graph is disconnected, then it is composed of multiple connected components and you run the proof once per component.

Comment: ,Thank you. So the assumption that we could have connected components is if we delete a vertex $u$ from the graph $G$ when we prove 6-colorable theorem?

Comment: @Avra: No, the assumption is that you *start* with either a connected graph or a disconnected graph (because there are no other kinds of graph you could possibly start with). By the time you are deleting vertices to prove the theorem, you've already assumed that the graph is connected.